# KOMA scripts: scrartcl: How to change the font color of the page number

Tags: koma-script

How can i change only the page number font color in the following latex code

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[automark,headsepline,footsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\begin{document}
CHECK PAGENUMBER FONT
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\addtokomafont{pagenumber}{...}` to your advantage. Assuming you want a red page number, you can use it as shown in the following example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[automark,headsepline,footsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\addtokomafont{pagenumber}{\color{red}}
\begin{document}
CHECK PAGENUMBER FONT
\end{document}
```

Comment: this is not part of this question. what is the purpose of `\usepackage[automark,headsepline,footsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}` I am just using it because without it page number does not work

Comment: I can't confirm "without it page number does not work". If I comment out line 4 of the example code in my answer, I still get a red page number.